# Is there a way to 'bump the version' without version commits?

Tags: git, npm, version

If I use tags with github, I don't need to make commits as the version number is separated from commits, however, if I am publishing to npm, I have to update in my package.json file which means I have to make loads of 'Bump version' commits which feels ugly. Is this accepted or is it better to lump them in with other work (*grimace* commit amending and force pushing sometimes if you forget to publish first. Terrible practice which should never be done I know).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the [commit-hooks](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version#commit-hooks) as well as the [version-tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version#git-tag-version):

```
npm version --commit-hooks false --git-tag-version false <major|minor|patch>
```

Comment: thanks, sorry I forgot to accept it! I used it today though over a year later!

Comment: How does this update the version permanently without creating a commit? By the look of it, I'd think it bumps the version, then it doesn't commit and doesn't tag. But then, the next person won't find the new version number. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Simone OP doesn't want to instantly commit the version bump but rather commit it later manually.